# How can I fix error (The property 'Guid' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate' or 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate'...)?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first, .net-core-2.1

I have a .NET Core 2.1 class library that is using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Database first. I was able to get it to create the models from the Db but any time I try to read from the database I get an error. There are no Guids in the table that I'm reading from and no foreign keys. The class has an int as its primary key. So, I'm not sure what is causing this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Side note: The SQL user is configured with read only access. I have no need to create, update, or delete records.

I was following the instructions here:

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx

ERROR:

> The property 'Guid' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate'
> or 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate' because the key value cannot be
> changed after the entity has been added to the store.

STACK TRACE:

> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.ValidateNoMutableKeys(IModel model,
> IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.RelationalModelValidator.Validate(IModel
> model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Internal.SqlServerModelValidator.Validate(IModel model, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnModelFinalized(IConventionModelBuilder
> modelBuilder)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.Model.FinalizeModel()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext
> context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
> at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite
> factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite
> constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, TArgument argument)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite
> callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider
> provider, Type serviceType)    at
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider
> provider)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_Model()    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityType() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.get_EntityQueryable()
> at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider() at System.Linq.Queryable.Where[TSource](IQueryable`1 source,
> Expression`1 predicate)    at
> Live_Db.LiveDbHelper.GetAllClients() in
> D:\VSProjects\Dashboard\Live_Db\LiveDbHelper.cs:line
> 18

DbContext:

```
public partial class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
    { }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=****; Database=****; User Id=****; Password=****");
        }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Client>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("Client", "app");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.ClientIdpublic)
                .HasName("IX_ctbl.sys.Client_PublicIDKey")
                .IsUnique();

            entity.Property(e => e.ClientId).HasColumnName("ClientID");

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingAddress1).HasMaxLength(200);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingAddress2).HasMaxLength(200);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingCity).HasMaxLength(200);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingContactName).HasMaxLength(200);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingCountry).HasMaxLength(200);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingEmail)
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingPhoneNumber).HasMaxLength(25);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingReferenceId)
                .HasColumnName("BillingReferenceID")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingState).HasMaxLength(200);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingStatusCode)
                .HasMaxLength(20)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.BillingZip).HasMaxLength(200);

            entity.Property(e => e.ClientIdpublic)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("ClientIDPublic")
                .HasMaxLength(15)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.ClientName)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            entity.Property(e => e.ClientSecret).HasMaxLength(300);

            entity.Property(e => e.DefaultAuthTypeId).HasColumnName("DefaultAuthTypeID");

            entity.Property(e => e.EvalEndDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Ftppwd)
                .HasColumnName("FTPPwd")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.InactiveMessage)
                .HasMaxLength(200)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            entity.Property(e => e.LogLocalDbcalls).HasColumnName("LogLocalDBCalls");

            entity.Property(e => e.RenewalDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.TokenForAutoNtauth)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasColumnName("TokenForAutoNTAuth")
                .HasMaxLength(50)
                .IsUnicode(false);
        });
    }
```

Read method:

```
public static List<Client> GetAllClients()
{
    try
    {
        List<Client> clients = new List<Client>();
        using (var db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            clients = db.Client.ToList();
        }
        return clients;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: And you are 100% sure that the database you execute against is the one your created the model against?

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ. Yes. it's the exact same connection string, user, and password. I used the 'reverse engineering' technique via the 'Scaffold-DbContext' command. Do you think there is a parameter I should have used that I missed maybe? I only gave it the bare minimum to scaffold the db.

Comment: This is not the answer but I did end up getting the error to stop. When I scaffolded the database, EFC pulled in all the tables which happened to be about 180 that I was not using. I commented out all the code that was not related to my task and the error went away. So, I still do not know what the real problem was but I do think a Guid in at least one of those tables is likely the source. I'll circle back to this later when I have time and post the true answer once I can narrow it down.

Comment: EF Core power tools has a GUI for selecting (a remebering) tables